# Is there any way to support HTML tags code inside bootstrap Tooltip?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

Recently I'm facing problem with  Bootstrap 3 Tooltip when I'm trying to add some html code inside title attribute. It shows me plain html tags code.

Here is the problem

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For getting html formatted result on tooltip you have to use **html: true** when initialize the bootstrap tooltip

Example:
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({ html: true });

Answer (score 3):

Yep. Depending on how you use it, you have to specify the `html` option as `true`. [Read the docs here.](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips-options)